# Fetch loop of custom post types with AJAX

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, ajax

I have a function that gets a list of CPT names and I need to call it on the front end on click and attach it to a container with ajax

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_structure_cp_list', 'get_structure_cp_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_structure_cp_list', 'get_structure_cp_list');
function get_structure_cp_list() {
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false,
);

$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
$post_types_array = array(); 

foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
    $post_types_array[] = $post_type;
}

$excluded_post_types = array("give_forms", "article", "structure", "links");
$post_types_array = array_diff($post_types_array, $excluded_post_types);

foreach ( $post_types_array  as $post_type ) {
    echo '<li>' . $post_type . '</li>';
}

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa56346_scripts', 100 );
function wpa56346_scripts() {
    global $post;
    if (is_singular( 'structure' )) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            if (user_can( $user, 'edit_posts')) {
                wp_enqueue_script(
                    'wpa56346_script',
                    get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/js/structure.js?ver=1.0',
                    array( 'jquery' ),
                    null,
                    false
                );
            }
        }
    }
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpa56346_script', 
        'ajax_object', 
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) 
    );
}

jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $(".create-btn .create").click( function() {
        $("#container").append("<div id='structure-form'></div>");
              $.ajax({  
                type: 'GET',  
                url: 'ajax_object.ajax_url',  
                data: { action : 'get_structure_cp_list' },  
                success: function(data){
                   $data = $(data);
                   alert('yes');
                   $( '#structure-form' ).html( $data ); 
                } 
              });       
    });
});
```

What's the cleanest way to accomplish this? My code is obviously mangled.

Comment: You can't enqueue your script and have your PHP callback all in the same function. You need to split your [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and your [WP AJAX Callback](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) into two difference function calls. Your callaback should probably return HTML back to your JS Success.

Comment: Did I edit it correctly? It's still not returning anything like that.

Comment: Still can't get this to work

Comment: Have you made any further attempts or read through my links? The code is still not set up properly - see [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Separate_JavaScript_File) which is also linked in my previous comment for an example. If you've made additional progress, please edit your questions to provide updated code.

Comment: Ok I updated the code in my question after reading through the links but it's still not returning the data. Can you show me a working example of how to do this?

Comment: You're missing the [`wp_ajax` action hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) that connect your javascript `action` parameter to your `get_structure_cp_list` php function

Comment: Oh yeah I had those and accidentally left them out. I updated the question but it's still not working.